# Unable to point VMC to my local cloud: HTTP exception: Errno::ECONNREFUSED:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: cloud-foundry

### WHAT AM I TRYING TO DO

Trying to setup a VCAP on a UBUNTU SERVER VM on my machine by following the steps mentioned at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/

### WHAT IS THE ISSUE

Things seemed to be working fine but at step5 (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/#step-5-validate-that-you-can-connect-and-tests-pass) I got an exception while trying to execute the following command - vmc target api.vcap.me

The exception that I see on my console is:

Host is not available or is not valid: 'http://api.vcap.me'

Would you like see the response? [yN]: y

HTTP exception: Errno::ECONNREFUSED:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)

### ANY OTHER RELEVANT INFO

For some earlier experiments I was using MicroCloud (provided as a download by CloudFoundry). I am having issues in pointing my VMC to this Microcloud as well.

On the Micro Cloud console I see the following message:

To access your Micro Cloud Foundry instance, use:
vmc target http://api.agoel.cloudfoundry.me

When I run this vmc command from the Ruby Command Prompt setup on my Windows7 I get following error:

Host is not available or is not valid: 'http://api.agoel.cloudfoundry.me'

Would you like see the response? [yN]: y

HTTP exception: Errno::ETIMEDOUT:A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
ost has failed to respond. - connect(2)

### WHATS DOES VMC INFO DISPLAY

I ran vmc info command on command prompt. It displayed following info

VMware's Cloud Application Platform

For support visit support DOT cloudfoundry DOT com

Target:   http:// api DOT cloudfoundry DOT com (v0.999)

Client:   v0.3.18

User:     ankitgoel1987@gmail.com

Usage:    Memory   (1.1G of 2.0G total)

```
      Services (2 of 16 total)

      Apps     (2 of 20 total)
```

### MY SETUP DETAILS

Windows7 running on 4GB RAM

Microcloud from Cloudfoundry already installed (this was done as part of some other exercise. My recent experiment requires me to setup a Ubuntu server with VCAP on it. So this MicroCloud should not really matter)

vmc 0.3.18 (installed on my Windows7 machine)

ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add in your hosts files the following entry:

IP_of_ubuntu_server vcap.me api.vcap.me

Comment: Thanks. Updating the host file fixed the issue.

Comment: Great. Remember to do the same for each application that you deploy on CF. E.g.

IP_of_ubuntu_server myspringexample.vcap.me
IP_of_ubuntu_server caldecott-7d43.vcap.me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid having to edit your hosts file every time you deploy a new app and depending on what virtualisation platform you are using you may be able to forward all traffic on port 80 for your own computer on to the VM.

*.vcap.me is set to resolve to 127.0.0.1 so this is an ideal solution. To do this you should set the network settings to NAT rather than Bridged (maybe you have done this already) and then set port 80 to forward to the IP of the guest OS. In VMWare Fusion for example this is as simple as editing a settings file.

Comment: Thanks Dan.This is some nice useful info.

Comment: Cud u help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535141/adding-a-new-runtime-to-cloudfoundry