# Adding a new runtime to CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am presently evaluating the possibility of adding a new runtime (for example Perl runtime) to CloudFoundry PaaS platform.

- Is it possible to add a new runtime (for example Perl runtime) to **CLOUDFOUNDRY PAAS PLATFORM (CloudFoundry.com)**? If yes please share some relevant details...
- Is it possible to add a new runtime (for example Perl runtime) to a **PRIVATE CLOUDFOUNDRY INSTANCE** ? If yes please share some relevant details...

Comment: Check out this link  on perl: http://programminggems.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/adding-a-runtime-and-framework-to-the-new-cloud-foundry/

Comment: I have been following this post. But it talks about adding runtimes to a private cloud. How about adding runtimes to Cloudfoundry PaaS platform? Is that allowed?

Comment: No, you need to modify the code for this, so it's only possible on your own custom CF instance.

Comment: Thanks Adi for the quick replies. I am pretty new to CloudFoundry - pardon my ignorance in case you feel I am asking trivial questions. Is it possible to setup my private cloudfoundry instance on a EC2 Ubuntu server and then push applications from my local machine? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add new runtimes to your own private instance of cloud
   foundry. [This](http://programminggems.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/adding-a-runtime-and-framework-to-the-new-cloud-foundry/) is a good starting point.
2. You may run this instance on a local server, or an a remote instance
   at [AWS](http://www.cloudsoftcorp.com/blog/first-steps-with-cloud-foundry-on-amazon-ec2/) or Rackspace.

Comment: I plan to setup the private instance of cloud foundry on a ubuntu server hosted on EC2. As you just confirmed this shouldn't be a problem. My questions is what goes into my windows host file? Should the entry be: <IPAddressOfEC2Machine> vcap.me api.vcap.me ?